# How i can make toast disappear?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

I have a problem with toast. How can I make toast disappear when the user successfully login to database.

The code for user fail to login like this:

class BuatLogin extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_layout.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login_layout Progress...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String usr = user.getText().toString();
        String pwd = pass.getText().toString();

        Log.d("1 "+usr, pwd);
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr", usr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", pwd));
        Log.d("2 "+usr, pwd);
        Log.d(usr,url_create_login);

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_login,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Buat Respond", json.toString());
        try {
            int sukses = json.getInt(TAG_SUKSES);

            if (sukses == 1) {
                String nim=json.getString(TAG_NIM);
                String jrs=json.getString(TAG_JRS);
                Log.d(TAG_NIM,nim);

                // sukses login
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mhs_main_layout.class);
                i.putExtra(TAG_NIM, nim);
                i.putExtra(TAG_JRS,jrs);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else if(sukses == 2) {
                String nip=json.getString(TAG_NIP);
                Log.d(TAG_NIP,nip);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admin_main_layout.class);
                i.putExtra(TAG_NIP, nip);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }else if(sukses == 3){
                setResult(100);
                //toas(100);
                //finish();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;

    }

    //Respon dari upadte buku class
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        int resultCode = 100;
        if (resultCode != 100); 
        {
         Toast.makeText(Login_layout.this, "Nip/Nim Atau Password TIdak Sesuai Silahkan Coba Lagi ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

But the toast keep coming up even the user successfully login and no error on the log cat. What can I do to make it disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do in a squeletal form:

```
int doInBackground(...) {
  blablabla...

  if (sukses == 1) {
     blablabla...
     // The value 1 will be returned to onPostExecute(int resultCode)
     // as the value for the parameter "resultCode":
     return 1; // or return sukses; same thing.
  } else if (sukses == 2) {
     blablabla...
     return 2; // or return sukses; same thing.
  } else {
     blablabla...
     return 3; // or return sukses; same thing.
  }
}

void onPostExecute(int resultCode) {
  // resultCode now contains the value returned by doInBackground():
  if (resultCode== 1) {
    Toast.makeText(Login_layout.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
  } else if (resultCode== 2) {
    Toast.makeText(Login_layout.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(Login_layout.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Feel free to complete this skeleton to your need.  I have transferred the call to finish() to the onPostExecute() just to be sure that the thread won't get cancelled before the toast is posted but you should search Google or make your own tests to find the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the call `setResult(100);` set the variable `resultCode` to 100 then the test `if (resultCode == 100)` will always be true and therefore the toast will always be displayed.

Are you sure that you don't want to test for `if (resultCode != 100)` instead?

Comment: still no result good sir... i try that but the toast keep came up when the user succses login..

Comment: The value passed as an argument to onPostExecute is equal to the value returned by the function doInBackground(). Without seeing this second function; it's hard to tell you what you are doing wrong.  You have shown us the code around the call to Toast() but you didn't have shown us the code where the real problem is located. Without seeing all the relevant code, it's impossible to tell you what's going on and showing us only some patches of code is rarely sufficient to locate an error.

Comment: You are always returning a Null value from doInBackground(); not a very useful thing to do if you want to modulate the display of a Toast to the user.  You should instead return a code indicating success or failure and catch it in the function onPostExecute() by using an integer parameter; something like onPostExecute(int resultCode).  As you are calling finish() to close your current activity in the case of success; it's also possible that the thread will be canceled and that the function onPostExecute will never get called.  Instead, you should call finish() from inside onPostExecute().

Comment: can you give a example solution on my project?

Comment: How can you write such an advanced code for testing a login, using json & company but at the same time, be unable to understand something as simple as returning the right value from the function doInBackground() to be used in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: I'm sory sir, I just don't understand. I apologies